# Find IP adresses and ports of devices connected to the same network

Tags: cordova, network-programming, udp, ssdp, dns-sd

I'm building an application for iOS and Android in angular/cordova where I want to find the IP and port of a certain device on my local network (dynamically), to be able to send post requests and talk to it through its API.

The API says that I could use `SSDP` or `DNS-SD` to discover the device. I've looked up these two helpers that could help me get a list of all connected devices on the network:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/mdns-js
- https://github.com/diversario/node-ssdp

But as far as I'm concerned node is a server-side framework, I can't just "require" the node modules in my app. Whats the most logical way to go here? I simply want to **get a list of all connected devices on my network**, is this hard to achieve?

Comment: _"But as far as I'm concerned this is server-aside code"_: both of the mentioned projects provide client-side code as the first example on their web pages. What is the problem?

Comment: Yeah but node is server side technology right? I can't just include it directly in my application.

Comment: Note: a server side program can be a 'client' to another program!

Comment: @novalain you haven't explained where your code will be running so I didn't know what technologies you can use... I suppose you mean you are building a web app that should run in a normal browser? Doing what you want might be impossible at this point: your app would have to be able to send multicast udp messages and I doubt javascript is allowed to do that in a browser. The W3C and browser developers are working on local discovery (e.g. Firefox does SSDP on it's own) but the features might not be available to web developers yet.

Comment: Alright that cleared thing a bit. I'm building the app in cordova so yes technically it should run in a normal browser (on android and ios). I've found some plugins: http://plugins.cordova.io/#/search?search=network, do you think any of these could help me with what I try to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Try this cordova plugin https://github.com/hsccorp/cordova-plugin-discovery
It let you discover any SSDP / UPnP / DLNA service on a local network
the hsccorp fork added ios support

Answer (score 0):

There's a Cordvoa ZeroConf plugin you can use for this:

https://github.com/becvert/cordova-plugin-zeroconf

This detects DNS-SD whereas the Cordova Plugin Discovery (in my tests) did not discover DNS-SD